# order of Math operations educational game

Tags: actionscript-3, math, operators

i am new to an AS3, but am trying now to build a game to improve knowledge of math operations order for kids.  I am breaking my head on how to implement this in an efficient way:

i display an expression `(2x(10-4/2)`. If they press any operator, but not `/` in brackets - error message comes, if they do the right choice - expression becomes `2x(10-2)`, etc.

I tried to put strings in `Array`, but they are not clickable then
I tried to create `MovieClip`s for each operator and answer as well, then to use `if` statement:

```
if (division in brackets clicked)
  removeChild(4/2);
  addChild(10-2);
```

It works, but .... looks very very ... long way to go

I am not asking to write a code for me, but may be give a hint of how to implement it

Thank you in advance if smbd has a desire to help.

Comment: What's your problem man ? Could you more explain the situation ? Do you have some code to show to us ? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do like this:
First, create a movieclip.
In this mc do like this:

```
**first frame  -> (2x(10-4/2)   [this can be a static textfield]
**second frame ->  2x(10-2)     [here put right simplification]
```

And now you have to listen to keyboard event...

if key pressed was  '/' [for example]
then your `your_mc.gotoAndStop(2);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you tziuka!  That is an idea i will surely look into.

Comment: On another thought, what happens in this case 2x(10-4x2)?

Comment: how to determine that the "x" in a brackets was pressed first, not the one outside?